# ssh into AWS pops up keychain

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

There is a EC2 instance in which my colleague is able to ssh in. When I try to ssh into it, it pops up the keychain password on my Mac OSX. [image: Keychain pop up]

I followed up this post for the solution.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18458/password-dialog-appears-when-ssh-private-key-permissions-are-set-to-0600
Not worked for me. 
This is the ssh command which I am using

```
ssh -i "mb_primary.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I have run
`chmod 400 mb_primary.pem`
and I have checked the private key also.
This is what happens when I try to ssh into the instance

```
debug1: Found key in /Users/adityashukla/.ssh/known_hosts:17  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey  
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey  
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adityashukla/.ssh/id_rsa  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey  
debug1: Trying private key: mb_primary.pem  
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.  
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Before the last statement, "it pops up the keychain as shown in the image.

Comment: who's the owner of the file? can you run ls -all on the folder where the file is

Comment: Have you tried `ssh-add /path/to/mb_primary.pem`?  What does `ssh-add -l` report?

Comment: (This should probably go in Server Fault, btw, as it's not about programming.)

Comment: And did you provide passphrase for the key in the prompt above?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri the folder is in Downloads, files have permissions.

Comment: @KarenB Tried ssh-add /path/to/mb_primary.pem . Still giving the same popup. When I do ssh-add -l, it return this: 2048 SHA256:PobdNUZ6XaFpC95dBgqSI9ORaT8xYlSWzsnshtQlpV8 /Users/adityashukla/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

Comment: @Jakuje In Passphrase, I pressed enter, it goes back to terminal and pops up "Permission Denied"

Comment: Are you sure the pem file doesn't have a passphrase?

Comment: My colleague says there isnt one. Thats the point. We never use passphrase.

Comment: When you got a prompt, there is passphrase or the key is somehow corrupted.